# SSH Connection via C#

Tags: c#, ssh

This is the situation. I have a Windows machine and a Linux machine. There is a shared drive between these two machines (which is mapped to Q:). I am trying to figure out how to create an SSH session at the Q: drive (shared drive) from C#. I am trying to use the SharpSsh library to do this.

This is what I have so far, however, it is giving me an error:

```
try
{
    ssh = new SshStream(host, username, password);

    Console.WriteLine("OK ({0}/{1})", ssh.Cipher, ssh.Mac);
    Console.WriteLine("Server version={0}, Client version={1}", ssh.ServerVersion, ssh.ClientVersion);
    Console.WriteLine("-Use the 'exit' command to disconnect.");
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Sets the end of response character
    ssh.Prompt = "#";
    //Remove terminal emulation characters
    ssh.RemoveTerminalEmulationCharacters = true;

    //Reads the initial response from the SSH stream
    Console.Write(ssh.ReadResponse());      // Blocking here

    while (true)
    {
        string command = Console.ReadLine();
        if (command.ToLower().Equals("exit"))
            break;

        //Write command to the SSH stream
        ssh.Write(command);
        //Read response from the SSH stream
        Console.Write(ssh.ReadResponse());
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

if(ssh != null)
{
    ssh.Close();
}
```

I have added the Tamir.SharpSSH.dll as a reference to the project, and I am using it in the project. There are two other dll's that are included with SharpSSH, do I need to add them as well to the references? The examples I have seen only have the Tamir.SharpSSH.dll as a reference.

I am not sure how to initiate the connection in the correct location, and how to submit commands properly to the ssh.

***UPDATE***

I realized I needed to close the SSH connection before ending the program. The error does not exist anymore, however, I am still not getting any information from my "ls" command.

***UPDATE***

I updated the code with what I have now. It seems like the ssh.ReadResponse() is blocking, which leads me to believe the server is not responding. Is that correct?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code for reading the output of the ls command?

Comment: @Kenster I updated the code. The ssh.ReadResponse() is hanging for some reason. I am not sure if I set the connection up properly.